# First Android App. edit_message cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android

**I did a lot of googling but other people don't seem to have the same problem as I.
The full error is :**

Multiple markers at this line.

-Line breakpoint:MainActivity - sendMessage(View) **I don't know what this means**

-edit_message caanot be resolved or is not a field

**Here is the line of code that's getting the error.**

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

**Here is my activity_main.xml**

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>
```

**Here is the full MainActivty.java**

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried a Rebuild on the project? Sometimes Eclipse (if that is what you are using) gets confused, so a rebuild helps out. The `Line breakpoint:MainActivity` means there is also a breakpoint there - double-click in the margin to make the breakpoint go away.

Comment: Have you solved it or not??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong layout. You put the field in `activity_main.xml`, but you are setting the content view to `activity_list_item`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the:

```
import android.R;
```

line.

This tells Android to use the internal resources R.java file, and not your project's. Removing it will fix the issue. You may have to go to `Project -> Clean` after doing this.

Comment: I did this, but instead of getting rid of the error, it made another one at
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);

Comment: Change that line to `setContentView(android.R.layout.activity_list_item);` and remove the import statement.

Comment: Import statement was removed already (or are you talking about another one?)
After changing the line, the error now says "R cannot be resolved into a variable" for both this line and the 
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

Answer (score 0):

Move:

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
}
```

to DisplayMessageActivity.java